# signed-off-by, acted-by, helpers helped-by, and improved-by in Git

Tags: java, git

I'm working on Git Repository, and I need to get all the developers' names for each commit. I know that to get Author name and Committer name, we use `--pretty="format:%an - %cn"`. However, there are other developers' names like signed-off-by, acted-by, helpers helped-by, and improved-by; how can I get this data, and if also there are other features ?

I would like to save the author name and the committer name of each commit in Java variables. Besides, if there are one of the previous features for this commit, I would like to save it as well. Is it possible to do that, and if so, how?

Comment: Have a look at [git rev-parse](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html).

Comment: rev-parse is not what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

This is usually kept in your issue tracking system (like Jira, for example). You can usually take a look at the history of the ticket and see who checked what checkbox and moved the issue into a new state. Git only tracks committers and authors.

If you have stored this information in the commit messages themselves, you should be able to use grep on the git log output to extract that information. It would help if you are using some convention to the commit messages to make this easier.

Comment: I would like to save the author name and the committer name of each commit in Java variables. Besides, if there are one of the features like signed-off-by for this commit, I would like to save it as well. How can I do that?

Comment: You could do that by merging that feature into a branch called signed-off. So if something is in that branch, you know that it's been signed off. But the better solution is to leave this to an issue tracker like jira. Rubymine is a free one.